# Problems With Client Side Prediction for X-Velocity in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, websocket, game-development, multiplayer

So I'm trying to code a simple online multi player game using JavaScript and WebSockets.
And I'm currently working on combatting lag issues:
To do so I measure the amount of time it takes for the message containing the updated position of a player to get from the player's computer to the server and then to all the other player's computers, then I apply physics forces to the position according to that amount.
I have the physics applied using a method on the player class that looks something like this:

```js
  // dt is deltaTime
  update(dt) {
    const groundLevel = 350;

    this.yVal += this.weight * dt;
    this.y += this.yVal * dt;
    if (this.y > groundLevel) {
      while (this.y > groundLevel) {
        this.y -= this.yVal / Math.abs(this.yVal);
      }
      this.yVal = 0;
    }

    this.xVal /= this.friction * dt;
    this.x += this.xVal * dt;
  }
```

Then I call the function repeatedly when getting an updated position, like this:

```js
  // p is the player
  // data is the object sent by the server containing the required data, and data.data is the player's transform data.
  p.setData(data.data);
  // 16.4 is about 1/60 seconds - simulating the average fps of 60
  // data.time is the time when the message was sent.
  let timeTook = new Date().getTime() - data.time;
  for (let i = 0; i < timeTook ; i += 16.4) {
    p.update(16.4);
  }
```

This works perfectly fine with the y position:
as you can see in [this clip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyTgt.gif) - where I simulated a 1 second lag - after the 1s delay, the object jumps to the exact position it should appear in.

**However**, when I try to move the player left or right, the position becomes way off!
As you can see in [this clip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HV3D3.gif) - which has the same lag - the object moves in one window farther than in the other.

I have no idea why this happens, or why it only happens to the x position, and I'd like any help I can get.

Answer (score 0):

**I Solved It!**

Turns out my problem had nothing to do with the way I handled the position update, but rather with my `update` method:
basically, when I wrote:

```js
this.xVal /= this.friction*dt
```

I made it so that the `xVal` property would decrees faster/slower depending on the delta time.

Let me explain:

Lets say I have a starting `xVal` of 1 and a `friction` of 1.5, and I have 2 different computers that run the update function for 1 second. but one computer runs at 2fps and the other at 4fps.
That means that one computer would run this code twice:

```js
// 1.5*500=750 (500 is dt)
this.xVal /= 750;
```

Which results in an `xVal`of 1/562500.
But the other computer would run this 4 times:

```js
// 1.5*250=375 (500 is dt)
this.xVal /= 375;
```

Which results in an `xVal`of 1/52787109.375.
As you can see, one will move faster than the other, which is a problem.

To combat this, we can change the code so it subtracts from `xVal` rather than dividing it:

```js
// Checks if the subtraction wouldn't flip the direction
if (Math.abs(this.xVal) > this.friction * dt)
  // If it isn't, it subtracts
  this.xVal -=
  this.friction * dt
  // Makes the subtraction poisitve/negative depending on whether the current xVal is poisitve/negative.
  * (this.xVal / Math.abs(this.xVal));
// If it is it sets xVal to 0
else this.xVal = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

what if you just send the signal and not the displacement values over the server and make a call to the motion function on evey signal on the other side so it will execute just the same movement. and not a correction of the realtime position?

Comment: Well, the whole point of the correction is to prevent lag. If I were to do what you suggested (assuming I understood it correctly), then there will be lag, since the motion function will be called only after the message got from the server to the user.

Comment: Also worth noting I solved at the end